# Unable to remove callbacks in Bokeh Server (ValueError: callback already ran or was already removed, cannot be removed again)

Tags: python, django, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh Server with Django to animate some charts that shows multiple series changing over time.
I'm currently trying to automate the slider to progress the time series.

Unfortunately I am experiencing two issues (that are probably related).  The first is that the although the animation starts (the slider moves and 'play' changes to 'pause' on the button), the chart is not updated.  The second is that any attempt to stop the slider (clicking on the 'pause' button) raise the error:

`ValueError: callback already ran or was already removed, cannot be removed again`

The slider continues to move.

Django is making a request to the server for a server_document, passing 'pk' as an argument:

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bokeh.embed import server_document

def getchart(request, pk):
    key = pk
    script = server_document(url="http://localhost:5006/bokeh_server",
                             arguments={"pk": pk,
                                        },
                             )
    return render(request, 'testserver.html', {'script':script})
```

The bokeh server receives the request, finds the data associated with 'pk' then builds a chart with animation.

*main.py*

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from copy import deepcopy
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, Button
from bokeh.models.widgets import TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import column, row


"""
Get arguments from request
"""
args = curdoc().session_context.request.arguments
pk = int(args.get('pk')[0])

"""
get data for graph from file and initialise variables
...
Replaced with example data in data_dict
"""
data_dict={'xdata':[[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12], [4, 8, 16, 0, 13, 21, -3, 9, 21]],
      'ydata':[[4, 8, 16, 0, 13, 21, -3, 9, 21], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12]]}

no_of_series = len(data_dict.get('xdata'))
length_of_series = len(data_dict.get('xdata')[0])


"""
Initialise ColumnDataSources
"""
graph_source = ColumnDataSource(data=deepcopy(data_dict)) #current data that will be displayed

"""
set graph_source to empty at start
"""
def initialise_graph_data(source):
    fullxdata = source.data['xdata']
    fullydata = source.data['ydata']
    i = 0
    while i < len(full_xdata):
        source.data['xdata'][i] = fullxdata[i][0:1]
        source.data['ydata'][i] = fullydata[i][0:1]
        i += 1

initialise_graph_data(graph_source)

"""
format graph
"""
tools="pan, wheel_zoom, reset"
p = figure(tools=tools)
p.multi_line(xs='xdata', ys='ydata', source=graph_source,)

"""
Interactive slider
"""
def animate_update():
    tick = slider.value + 1
    slider.value = tick

def slider_update(attr, old, new):
    tick = slider.value
    """
    create display data for each series, starting at 0 and ending at the current tick value
    """
    i=0
    while i < no_of_series:
       graph_source.data['xdata'][i] = data_dict['xdata'][i][0:tick]
       graph_source.data['ydata'][i] = data_dict['ydata'][i][0:tick]
       i += 1

slider = Slider(start=0, end=length_of_series, value=0, step=1)

slider.on_change('value', slider_update)

def animate():
    if button.label == "► Play":
        button.label = "❚❚ Pause"
        curdoc().add_periodic_callback(animate_update, 200)
    else:
        button.label = "► Play"
        curdoc().remove_periodic_callback(animate_update)

button = Button(label="► Play", width=60)
button.on_click(animate)
layout = row(column(p), button, slider)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

With `print(graph_source.data['xdata'][i])` at the end of `slider_update()` it's clear that the source data is updating as expected, but the chart does not refresh.

I expect the issue is being caused by the multiple use of `curdoc()` in *main.py*, or I'm misusing `server_document()` in *views.py*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main.py` code has multiple errors:

1. Same columns have different names: `xdata`, `x_data`, `x`
2. You can't update data source columns in-place. It's better to use `stream`, `patch`, change a single column with `ds.data['x'] = ...`, or change the full data with `ds.data = ...`. With the latter, you would be able to use dict comprehension and avoid storing `no_of_series` entirely
3. `remove_periodic_callback` accepts callback ID that was returned by `add_periodic_callback`

With these fixed, your code will work.